# Partial Curl get dissapears when home button clicks

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer

I am doing a partial curl using CATransition, It works fine but After home button click while the page is curved and trying to resume then the curved page gets disappear.

Here is my code

```
self.animation = [CATransition animation];
[self.animation setDelegate:self]; [animation setDuration:1.00];
[self.animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

if (!curled){
    self.animation.type = @"pageCurl"; 
    self.animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    self.animation.endProgress = 0.50; 
}

[self.animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];

[[[self view] layer] addAnimation:self.animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
}
```

Comment: While home button is pressed -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated is not get fired. I want to hold the animation as such. for eg: google maps, go to settings then a page curl will come, after home buuton is pressed and come back to app again that curl will be there right?. But in my app that curl animation is not get maintained